# How do I install not one project but solution

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, installation

I have solution, which contains 2 projects. I use Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects. I need to install both of them in one folder.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects, have you tried to add your two projects(Project Output) into one Setup project’s `Application Folder`?

From Setup project > click Application Folder > in the right panel > right-click the white space > Add > Project Output… > choose your first project and select `Primary output` > OK, then do the same steps which mentioned above and add your second project. You can also try to create the shortcut on `User’s Desktop`…

After that, please try to build your solution and build the Setup project. Then, go to the Setup project folder and run the `.exe` file, and see if the projects are installed in one folder, and confirm whether this meets your requirements.

Regards.